# SQL Server stored procedure keeps waiting with "awaiting command"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a very complex stored procedure in my SQL Server 2008 R2 that inserts large amounts of data into several tables of a database.

A copy of this procedure runs fine on several other servers. I usually use a job in the server agent to run the procedure, but when I do this on my dev server, the job fails, displaying a snippet of the code in the log, but little else.

When I execute the stored procedure outside of the job, the activity monitor displays the proces as Task state: "Suspended", command: "Awaiting command" and waittype alternating between "IO_Completion", "PAGEIOLatch_SH" and blank.

[This page](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/02/10/sql-server-io_completion-wait-type-day-10-of-28/) suggests there might be something with memory allocation, but there is still 9gb left on the disk writing the data and logs (not much, but it should be enough).

Does anybody know what the wait type IO_Completion means in context of executing a stored procedure?

Comment: You've asked about an X, Y Problem. If you posted the proc and the error, you'd have a better chance at getting an answer to your *actual* problem.

Comment: [PAGEIOLATCH_SH](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/pageiolatch_sh/) is typically the system waiting for data pages to be read from disk or memory.  [IO_COMPLETION](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/io_completion/) is typically the system waiting for non-data pages to be read from disk or memory. This is not necessarily an indication that the problem is IO, however, since *most* SQL Server operations are IO bound. If you really want to dig into it you can start [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) but it may be a red herring.

Comment: Without knowing the configuration of your dev system, it's really hard to say what the issue is.  It sounds like you've got both the logs and the data files on the same disk, which isn't going to help for large inserts if you haven't pre-grown your files.  It could be an issue with memory exhaustion if your dev system doesn't have much memory.  It could be tempdb contention, too, since that's what SQL Server uses when it needs a scratch space.

Comment: @scimon, you might be right. Still, the actual procedure is over 300 lines long and there is no error in the log, just a snippet of code, as I said. However, I understand that my question is a bit vague in that aspect.

Comment: @scimon: you *were* right: the task state was not the core problem; there was a problem with the query in the stored procedure. I just couldn't see the real error while the query was still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had canceled the running stored procedure, it did print an error that was easily resolved. It seems a lack of memory prevented the server from returning the error properly, causing it to get stuck in the 'awaiting command' wait state.